# sidekiq monitoring for admin only in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, sidekiq

I'm following [this wiki](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Monitoring), and have put the following code into my routes.rb:

```
authenticate :user, lambda { |u| u.admin? } do
 mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'
end
```

This lets me restrict access to the `/sidekiq` path to only users who are also admin. However, this code signs me out and makes me sign back again in every time I go to a new path thereunder. I click Queues, Retries, Scheduled, Dead, etc, they all take me to my app's sign in page. Repeat cycle. Why is that? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your application has been wrapped up by another authentication layer (Gem), could you please double check your application? if you're using `Devise` or `Clearance` then you should take a look at your wiki link again to configure with the right way (with Devise or Clearance).

Comment: I'm using Devise. The code I'm using is from the wiki section for Devise.

Comment: Are you using Redis to save login session? if so, we can try using this configuration `Sidekiq::Web.set :sessions, false` to solve this problem.

Comment: ah ok i see that it was down under "Sessions being lost" :(

thank you!